# Package using pcl make error

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-ros, package, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I used a source code from

[pcl/range_image & visualization](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/range_image_visualization.php#range-image-visualization)

in my ROS package(pcl_tutorial) to create a range image. But when i make the package, i get an error

In file included from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/pcl-1.5/pcl/visualization/range_image_visualizer.h:44:0,

from /home/karthik/Desktop/OpenCV/sandbox/pcl_tutorial/src/pcd2range_image.cpp:13:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/pcl-1.5/pcl/visualization/image_viewer.h:41:28:

fatal error: vtkImageViewer.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot contd1]
[image: sc contd2]
[image: sc contd 3]

I have highlighted the lines which i think has the error. Please help me out with this error.

I would like to make you know that :- as in the highlighted lines /opt/ros/fuerte/pcl-1.5/pcl/visualization/image_viewer.h ,i checked out the directory, which is named pcl-1.5. But i installed pcl from

[pcl/Downloads](http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html)

(prebuilt binaries) which happens to be pcl-1.6(as seen in ubuntu software center)

And the error vtkImageViewer.h , from my synaptics package manager, i found vtk has dependencies of pcl 1.6 which are installed and pcl 1.5 which are not installed.

Should i uninstall all pcl-1.6 packages and install pcl-1.5 because my ROS uses pcl-1.5(as i assume from the above) or should i reinstall vtk5.8.0-5(as seen from synaptic package manager) is there any other way?? please help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49978/package-using-pcl-make-error/) by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I solved the error [from answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org/question/39444/pcl-visualizer-error/?answer=39744#post-id-39744) .Now I am able to build the package without any error.

---

Originally posted by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) with karma: 48 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2017-05-06**:
Putting the solution itself or the summary of it would be better.